# How to construct a convergent subsequence of $\sin(n)$

Tags: real-analysis

I know that $\sin(n)$ has a convergent subsequence, but is there any way to actually construct a convergent subsequence of this sequence, or does existence just follow from the Bolzano Weierstrass theorem, and a sequence cannot be constructed?

Answer (score 2):

Let $p_n/q_n$ be the sequence of convergents of the simple continued fraction for $\pi$.  Then
$q_n \to \infty$ and $|p_n/q_n - \pi| < 1/q_n^2$.  We have
$$|\sin(p_n)| = |\sin(p_n - q_n \pi)| < |p_n - q_n \pi| < 1/q_n$$

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [continued fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction) representation of $2\pi$ to find a (rapidly) increasing sequence of integers such that $\sin(n)$ approaches $\sin(2\pi) = 0$.

The sequence of convergents of $2\pi$ is
$$  6,\frac{19}{3},\frac{25}{4},\frac{44}{7},\frac{333}{53},\frac{710}{113},\frac{103993}{16551},\frac{312689}{49766},\frac{1980127}{315147},\frac{2292816}{364913}, \dots  $$

Ignoring the denominators, we have the subsequence

\begin{align*}
 \sin (6) &= -0.279415 \\
 \sin (19) &= 0.149877 \\
 \sin (25) &= -0.132352 \\
 \sin (44) &= 0.0177019 \\
 \sin (333) &= -0.00882117 \\
 \sin (710) &= 0.0000602887 \\
 \sin (103993) &= -0.0000191293 \\
 \sin (312689) &= 2.900699 \times 10^{-6} \\
 \sin (1980127) &= -1.725139 \times 10^{-6} \\
 \sin (2292816) &= 1.175559 \times 10^{-6} \\
&\vdots
\end{align*}